# Compile Error: Object Required - Dynamic File Selection VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble debugging the Compile Error - Object Required bug from my code. Any suggestions on how to tweak my code?

```
Sub Select_DataSource()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant 
Dim OpenBook As Workbook 
Dim LastRow As Long     

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
  FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*") 
  If FileToOpen <> False Then
       Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
       Set LastRow = OpenBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:F" & LastRow).Copy
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LGP_DATA").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       OpenBook.Close False
  End If 
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't `Set` long variables, only objects.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know that. Took out the Set. Code works. Thanks so much!